# Difference between Server.MapPath and Page.MapPath

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between those two?
If I only want to retrieve the absoluate path to an image on web server, is Server.MapPath safer in any case?
I'm using Page.MapPath right now, but it won't work if control was created in WebService since control.Page property become null?
Whether Server.MapPath always work?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1319058.aspx

Comment: @RPM1984: Please, don't post links without explaining what is that. Why don't you gather the information and try to explain it on an answer? And by the way, look at those answers, they are just spam, they aren't answers at all.

Comment: i wasn't saying "that is the answer", i was highlighting how people don't even bother googling anymore. I literally c+p'd the post title into google, and a thread came up with the EXACT same question. google first, SO second. thats just me. And one of those answers is valid (and from a Microsoft MVP), be careful in dismissing so easily.

Comment: @RPM1984: I've read that page before posting question here. I don't think the answers there are clearly enough in my case. How do you know I didn't googling this topic?

Comment: Then mention that in your question (i read this article, however i dont understand it/doesnt apply to me because of xxx). Anyway, looks like you got a "clear answer" from @BrunoLM.

Comment: You don't need to google it to answer my question (you can assume I did it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seem through [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and it seems both methods end up calling the same base method.

So you can use whichever fits better.

If you don't have the `Page`, you can get it through the context handler. (It will be null if you are not actually in a page).

```
var Page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
```